# How to communicate with an API

Tags: php, wordpress, api

I am developing a Wordpress plugin that needs to retrieve an Affiliate ID from an outside website - a website based upon [this API](http://www.filmon.com/page/api).

The idea is this:

1) Refer the user to the website and have them sign up as affiliate.

2) User returns to the Wordpress CMS and enters their Affiliate ID

3) Somehow I would like to verify the correct/incorrect Affiliate ID after saving user input.

So my question is 2 parts:

a. How do I accomplish validation of a user's affiliate ID?,

b. Do I need to load the API inside of my Wordpress plugin, or do I communicate with the API through the outside server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding b):

You need to make the calls within your WordPress plugin. I got the feeling that you're missing some basics. Please have a look at [this article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/a-beginners-introduction-to-http-and-rest/) about HTTP & REST.

Basically you only have to make a POST request and the API returns you what ever you want.

Comment: I will start here.  Thanks for pointing me in the correct direction.